# What tools are available for distributing and syncing firewall rule-sets to multiple devices?

Tags: network, firewalls

I am looking for a solution to be able to distribute and sync firewall rule-sets to multiple devices. There are a few solutions out there such as [Playbook by Matasano](http://www.matasano.com/playbook/) but it comes with an expensive price tag.

Is anyone familiar with any other solutions that are cheaper or ideally free and allow for the syncing of Cisco and iptables rule-sets?

Answer (score 7):

A couple engineers I know are using [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) to maintain iptables rule sets.

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Module_Iptables_Patterns
https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-iptables

Comment: Puppet looks really interesting. Going to give it a go next week.

Comment: I'm one of those 'engineers'. I use the first method, and it works great. I have on my list testing the second.

Answer (score 3):

Most enterprise class firewalls (I know Check Point and MS ISA, I'm sure others too - but not iptables) allow you to distribute rulesets etc to all the managed firewalls, from a single management console.

Of course, thats each for a single vendor's product... For different types of firewalls, I'm familiar with [Tufin](http://www.tufin.com/), but I think they're pretty high-end - and expensive.

Answer (score 1):

FWbuilder might be of interest to you
**http://www.fwbuilder.org/**

This is a GUI tool to help you configure and distribute (i.e. push) firewall configurations for various firewall implementations.

It 'compiles' network access rules and firewall configuration options into version specific syntax and can push it through SSH to many firewall implementations like Cisco ACL's, iptables, and openbsd PF.

Central management of various devices in combination with version control of the rulesets of these nodes is a production quality feature that can also be seen in enterprise firewall management applications.